# How to Implement "Your contact just joined app" feature

Tags: flutter, database-design, contacts

I am building a mobile app (in flutter firebase, but the answer does not have to be firebase specific). And I would like to implement a feature that notifies users whenever anyone from their contact list joins the app. This seems like a very EXPENSIVE feature.

At the top of my head, I see a lambda/cloud function that is triggered everytime a user joins and then searches a database of users and their respective contacts for the existence of the new user's phone number. To me, this solution does not scale well for two reasons: if the number of total users is in the millions and the number of users joining simultaneously is a lot.

My better solution is to get the user's contacts upon joining and then searching a database of current users contacts for any of the phone numbers of the newly joined user.

Is there a solution better than the second one? If so, what is it? If the second solution is standard, **what kind of backend storage mechanism provides the best search and retrieval time for a database of users and their respective contacts?**

Answer (score 1):

In the case of large users ill not do first solution because  that may slow the sign up process instead i will creat a cron job that runs at a specific time or periodically it will get the list of the latest users signed up that day or that hour whatever you prefer then that cron will check the new user if related to any user in the databases and send a notification right away, or a better solution create a temporary table in a database in another server insert the notification informations into the other server, creat another cron job in the second  server it will run at a specific time to sendthe notification